# python non-specific argument

Tags: python, arguments

I have the code

```
class Button(object):
'''A simple Button class to represent a UI Button element'''

def __init__(self, text = "button"):
    '''Create a Button and assign it a label'''
    self.label = text

def press(self):
    '''Simply print that the button was pressed'''
    print("{0} was pressed".format(self.label))

class ToggleButton(Button):
def __init__(self, text, state=True):
    super(ToggleButton, self).__init__(text)
    self.state = state

def press(self):
    super(ToggleButton, self).press()
    self.state = not self.state
    print('{0} is now'.format(self.label), 'ON' if self.state else 'OFF')
```

When I input

```
tb = ToggleButton("Test", False) 
tb.press()
tb.press()
```

it works fine and returns

```
Test was pressed
Test is now ON
Test was pressed
Test is now OFF
```

but what I want is to have the text parameter optional, so that if I input

```
b = ToggleButton()
b.press()
```

it will return

```
ToggleButton was pressed
ToggleButton is now OFF
```

any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Follow the example of the `state` parameter and give `text` a default value as well.

```
class ToggleButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, text="ToggleButton", state=True):
        super(ToggleButton, self).__init__(text)
        self.state = state
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider something adaptive such as this:

```
class ToggleButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ToggleButton, self).__init__(*args)
        self.state = kwargs.get('state', True)
```